# How to effectively use azureml.exceptions.WebserviceException for efficient REST API Error Management?

Tags: rest, azure-web-app-service, azure-machine-learning-service

In Azure Machine Learning Service, when we deploy a Model as an AKS Webservice Endpoint, how can we raise exceptions to let the end-user get proper feedback if their API call is unsuccessful? Azure mentions using `azureml.exceptions.WebserviceException` in their [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.exceptions.webserviceexception?view=azure-ml-py). However, how do we use this class to raise exceptions in case the API call cannot be processed properly and the end-user is responsible for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To raise exceptions to let the end-user get proper feedback if their API call is unsuccessful, we use the [`azureml.contrib.services.aml_response.AMLResponse` Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-contrib-services/azureml.contrib.services.aml_response.amlresponse?view=azure-ml-py).

Example of use in `score.py`:

```
if [some-condition]:    
    return AMLResponse("bad request", 500)
```

Documentation Link can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-advanced-entry-script#binary-data).

Answer (score 0):

The following code example shows how to handle the `WebserviceException`, which is a subclass of `AzureMLException`. In the code, if the check of the service fails, then the `WebserviceException` is handled and a message can be printed.

```
from azureml.core.model import InferenceConfig
   from azureml.core.webservice import AciWebservice


   service_name = 'my-custom-env-service'

   inference_config = InferenceConfig(entry_script='score.py', environment=environment)
   aci_config = AciWebservice.deploy_configuration(cpu_cores=1, memory_gb=1)

   service = Model.deploy(workspace=ws,
                          name=service_name,
                          models=[model],
                          inference_config=inference_config,
                          deployment_config=aci_config,
                          overwrite=True)
   service.wait_for_deployment(show_output=True)
```

Full sample is available from: https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/deployment/deploy-to-cloud/model-register-and-deploy.ipynb

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: No, what I want to know is: 
Example: I am storing timestamp for one of the features in the input. I want to check if the timestamp is greater than a cached timestamp. If it is so, we process the request; else we let the end-user know that their request needs to be changed with a proper Exception Message.